# postgres update failed, when comparing a string whose length is greater than 255+ with a column value

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, postgresql-9.5, ktor, kotlin-exposed

The issue is basically happening, when i am comparing a string whose length is greater than 255+ with a column value, whose code is as follows,

```
transaction {
        TableUserAccessToken.update({
                    (TableUserAccessToken.accessToken eq argAccessToken) 
        }) {
            it[updatedAt] = DateTime.now()
            it[isActive] = argDisableToken
        }
    }
```

Basically i want to update a row based on 3 parameters i.e.

```
object TableUserAccessToken : Table(name = "AccessToken") {
  val createdAt = datetime("created_at").clientDefault { DateTime.now() }
  val updatedAt = datetime("updated_at").nullable()
  val accessToken = varchar("accessToken", MAX_COLUMN_LENGTH)
  val refreshToken = varchar("refreshToken", MAX_COLUMN_LENGTH)
  val isActive = bool("isActive").default(true)
  val userId = integer("userId").references(TableUser.id, onDelete = ReferenceOption.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ReferenceOption.CASCADE)
}
```

and here it fails to update with following message as follows,

```
"message" : "Value 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJBdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbiIsImlzcyI6InJlcHJhdG9yLmtoYXRhYm9va0FjY291bnQiLCJ1c2VyUGhvbmVOdW1iZXIiOiI5MDQxODY2MDU1IiwidXNlck9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbklkIjotMSwiZXhwIjoxNjAxOTAyNTYwLCJ1c2VySWQiOjF9.q6t0_q2jaY24Y-QZMF8GYduqhtIAaYRjFyq_dhAscgI6yxZUglERzaf3j-4RGWmSZXGqgJU8FcipbW9gbo9Ygw' can't be stored to database column because exceeds length (255)"
```

and if i just provide one parameter it works, even if access token of 2 doesnot exist in table database, query as follows,

```
 transaction {
        TableUserAccessToken.update({
                    (TableUserAccessToken.accessToken eq "2")
        }) {
            it[updatedAt] = DateTime.now()
            it[isActive] = argDisableToken
        }
    }
```

and related user table is as follows,

```
object TableUser : IntIdTable(name = "Users") {
   val mobile = text("mobileNumber")
   val verificationStatus = bool("isVerified").default(false)
   val parentId = integer("parentId").default(-1)
   val createdAt = datetime("created_at").clientDefault { DateTime.now() }
}
```

But i have to update based on multiple conditions, It will be very great, if you guys could assist me.

Table Creation Logs,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, "mobileNumber" TEXT NOT NULL, "isVerified" BOOLEAN DEFAULT false NOT NULL, "parentId" INT DEFAULT -1 NOT NULL, created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accesstoken (created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, updated_at TIMESTAMP NULL, "accessToken" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, "refreshToken" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, "isActive" BOOLEAN DEFAULT true NOT NULL, "userId" INT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT fk_accesstoken_userid_id FOREIGN KEY ("userId") REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Account Creation Exposed logs for api(/api/v1/accounts),

```
SELECT users.id, users."mobileNumber", users."isVerified", users."parentId", users.created_at FROM users WHERE (users."mobileNumber" = '9041866055') AND (users."parentId" = -1) LIMIT 1
INSERT INTO users (created_at, "isVerified", "mobileNumber", "parentId") VALUES ('2020-10-05 20:57:47.393000', false, '9041866055', -1)
INSERT INTO accesstoken ("accessToken", created_at, "isActive", "refreshToken", updated_at, "userId") VALUES ('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJBdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbiIsImlzcyI6InJlcHJhdG9yLmtoYXRhYm9va0FjY291bnQiLCJ1c2VyUGhvbmVOdW1iZXIiOiI5MDQxODY2MDU1IiwidXNlck9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbklkIjotMSwiZXhwIjoxNjAxOTk4MDY3LCJ1c2VySWQiOjF9.BQ2iYk03cSrvwEQ4XGmrlZHsiZXVooiwink7uIQ1YiqaSlcaOJCV9peNoq7UC_1I2WvYPBB6epvDCINwcPXhWA', '2020-10-05 20:57:47.483000', true, 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJBdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbiIsImlzcyI6InJlcHJhdG9yLmtoYXRhYm9va0FjY291bnQiLCJ1c2VyUGhvbmVOdW1iZXIiOiI5MDQxODY2MDU1IiwidXNlck9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbklkIjotMSwiZXhwIjoxNjAyNzc1NjY3LCJ1c2VySWQiOjF9.F3ktJodIwNpkmtl6rLNT5IbzbRLZxs5QZN4N8mqlxd8pb-7eUx0Fx_AQj88M0JqQ_P40fS91ya6DGztjjqBwOg', NULL, 1)
```

Refresh Token Logs for api(/api/v1/accounts/refreshToken),
Crash Log for exposed as follows,

```
ERROR r.k.error.ErrorFeature - Caught exception: Value 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJBdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbiIsImlzcyI6InJlcHJhdG9yLmtoYXRhYm9va0FjY291bnQiLCJ1c2VyUGhvbmVOdW1iZXIiOiI5MDQxODY2MDU1IiwidXNlck9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbklkIjotMSwiZXhwIjoxNjAxOTk4MDY3LCJ1c2VySWQiOjF9.BQ2iYk03cSrvwEQ4XGmrlZHsiZXVooiwink7uIQ1YiqaSlcaOJCV9peNoq7UC_1I2WvYPBB6epvDCINwcPXhWA' can't be stored to database column because exceeds length (255)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJBdXRoZW50aWNhdGlvbiIsImlzcyI6InJlcHJhdG9yLmtoYXRhYm9va0FjY291bnQiLCJ1c2VyUGhvbmVOdW1iZXIiOiI5MDQxODY2MDU1IiwidXNlck9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbklkIjotMSwiZXhwIjoxNjAxOTk4MDY3LCJ1c2VySWQiOjF9.BQ2iYk03cSrvwEQ4XGmrlZHsiZXVooiwink7uIQ1YiqaSlcaOJCV9peNoq7UC_1I2WvYPBB6epvDCINwcPXhWA' can't be stored to database column because exceeds length (255)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.VarCharColumnType.notNullValueToDB(ColumnType.kt:541)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.IColumnType$DefaultImpls.valueToDB(ColumnType.kt:37)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.ColumnType.valueToDB(ColumnType.kt:71)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.api.PreparedStatementApi$DefaultImpls.fillParameters(PreparedStatementApi.kt:13)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatementImpl.fillParameters(JdbcPreparedStatementImpl.kt:9)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.Statement.executeIn$exposed_core(Statement.kt:53)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Transaction.exec(Transaction.kt:129)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Transaction.exec(Transaction.kt:115)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.Statement.execute(Statement.kt:29)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.QueriesKt.update(Queries.kt:179)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.QueriesKt.update$default(Queries.kt:176)
at reprator.khatabookAccount.accountService.data.db.DbAccountAccessTokenRepository$updateUserToken$2.invoke(DbAccountAccessTokenRepository.kt:35)
at reprator.khatabookAccount.accountService.data.db.DbAccountAccessTokenRepository$updateUserToken$2.invoke(DbAccountAccessTokenRepository.kt:12)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt$inTopLevelTransaction$1.invoke(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:170)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt$inTopLevelTransaction$2.invoke(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:211)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.keepAndRestoreTransactionRefAfterRun(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:219)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.inTopLevelTransaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:210)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt$transaction$1.invoke(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:148)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.keepAndRestoreTransactionRefAfterRun(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:219)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:120)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:118)
at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.ThreadLocalTransactionManagerKt.transaction$default(ThreadLocalTransactionManager.kt:117)
at reprator.khatabookAccount.accountService.data.db.DbAccountAccessTokenRepository.updateUserToken(DbAccountAccessTokenRepository.kt:34)
at reprator.khatabookAccount.accountService.data.AccountAccessTokenRepository$DefaultImpls.updateUserToken$default(AccountAccessTokenRepository.kt:16)
at reprator.khatabookAccount.accountService.domain.default.DefaultAccountResourceFactory.refreshToken(DefaultAccountResourceFactory.kt:83)
at reprator.khatabookAccount.accountService.domain.default.DefaultAccountFacade.refreshToken(DefaultAccountFacade.kt:37)
at reprator.khatabookAccount.accountService.controller.default.DefaultAccountController.refreshToken(DefaultAccountController.kt:32)
at reprator.khatabookAccount.accountService.controller.AbstractAccountController$getRoutes$2$1.invokeSuspend(AbstractAccountController.kt:25)
at reprator.khatabookAccount.accountService.controller.AbstractAccountController$getRoutes$2$1.invoke(AbstractAccountController.kt)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:323)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:168)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:188)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:31)
at io.ktor.routing.Routing.executeResult(Routing.kt:147)
at io.ktor.routing.Routing.interceptor(Routing.kt:34)
at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invokeSuspend(Routing.kt:99)
at io.ktor.routing.Routing$Feature$install$1.invoke(Routing.kt)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:323)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:168)
at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$1.invokeSuspend(ContentNegotiation.kt:107)
at io.ktor.features.ContentNegotiation$Feature$install$1.invoke(ContentNegotiation.kt)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:323)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:168)
at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$interceptCall$2.invokeSuspend(StatusPages.kt:101)
at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$interceptCall$2.invoke(StatusPages.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:91)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScopeKt.coroutineScope(CoroutineScope.kt:194)
at io.ktor.features.StatusPages.interceptCall(StatusPages.kt:100)
at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$Feature$install$2.invokeSuspend(StatusPages.kt:140)
at io.ktor.features.StatusPages$Feature$install$2.invoke(StatusPages.kt)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:323)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:168)
at io.ktor.features.CallLogging$Feature$install$1$invokeSuspend$$inlined$withMDC$1.invokeSuspend(CallLogging.kt:226)
at io.ktor.features.CallLogging$Feature$install$1$invokeSuspend$$inlined$withMDC$1.invoke(CallLogging.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startUndispatchedOrReturn(Undispatched.kt:91)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.withContext(Builders.common.kt:160)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.withContext(Unknown Source)
at io.ktor.features.CallLogging$Feature$install$1.invokeSuspend(CallLogging.kt:230)
at io.ktor.features.CallLogging$Feature$install$1.invoke(CallLogging.kt)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:323)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:168)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:188)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:31)
at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultEnginePipelineKt$defaultEnginePipeline$2.invokeSuspend(DefaultEnginePipeline.kt:121)
at io.ktor.server.engine.DefaultEnginePipelineKt$defaultEnginePipeline$2.invoke(DefaultEnginePipeline.kt)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(PipelineContext.kt:323)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.proceed(PipelineContext.kt:168)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.execute(PipelineContext.kt:188)
at io.ktor.util.pipeline.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.kt:31)
at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler$handleRequest$1.invokeSuspend(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:40)
at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler$handleRequest$1.invoke(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.UndispatchedKt.startCoroutineUndispatched(Undispatched.kt:55)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:111)
at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:158)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source)
at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler.handleRequest(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:30)
at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationCallHandler.channelRead(NettyApplicationCallHandler.kt:24)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:61)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:370)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My DB is: Postgres, version is 42.2.16,

JDBC DRIVER version 0.27.1

Exposed version 0.27.1

MAX_COLUMN_LENGTH = 1000

The whole source code can be found here, https://github.com/TheReprator/khatabookAccount

This is the actual issue,
https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/1029

Comment: There is no Postgres version "42.2.16" - that's the version of the JDBC driver.

Comment: org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.16, this is the gradle version, i am using

Comment: Fixed in Exposed 0.28,1. Please update